# Why can't I separate letters in a string?

Tags: arrays, c

I want to take all the letters in a string and put it in a array separately. But I am receiving some error and I could not figure out.

> **10  20  E:\FALL SEM 20-21\CS\C codes\Untitled3.c    [Warning] passing argument 2 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast**

My code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


char array[10][100],string[100];
int top=0;

void push(char elem)
{
    strcpy(array[top],elem);
    top++;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter the string: \n");
    fgets(string,100,stdin);
    int length;
    length=strlen(string);
    int i=0;
    while((string[i])!='\0')
    {
        push(string[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d",length);
}
```

Comment: If you want help with the error you need to show the error.

Comment: `strcpy()` is for copying *strings*, so both arguments should be `char*`. What do you want to do?

Comment: a string _is_ an array. If you want to make a copy of the string, just use `strcpy`, no need for your own `push` function trying to copy one char at a time: `strcpy(array[0], string);`. Or, if you want `string` copied 10 times into `array`, you can do that in a loop. Of course, make sure to stay in bounds.

Comment: @Baba_yaga Your function push does not make a sense. Describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: The warning you should be getting on `strcpy(array[top],elem)` should be paramount. Turn up warnings and, even more important, enable whatever option(s) are necessary to consider warnings as fatal errors. At this stage (and nearly all others) that's exactly what they are: errors.

Comment: @yano I tried your way but still I get same warnings

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There's no practical application for what your code is trying to do. Even if you satisfy the warning and push a 2 character string as in the answer below, you'll overflow `array` if `string` is > 10 chars, and you have all that extra horizontal space ([100]) in `array`, 98 of which is unused. Can you please try to describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: You say you keep getting warnings ... are you sure you're making changes to the source, saving, compiling from that source? Neither `strcpy(array[0], string);` nor the answer below should produce the warning in your OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcpy()` is for copying strings (sequences of characters terminated by a null-character). To use that, you should make strings from the characters and pass them. Also you have to fix the type of the argument of `push()`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


char array[10][100],string[100];
int top=0;

void push(const char* elem) /* use const char* to receive strings that won't be modified */
{
    strcpy(array[top],elem);
    top++;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter the string: \n");
    fgets(string,100,stdin);
    int length;
    length=strlen(string);
    int i=0;
    while((string[i])!='\0')
    {
        char str[2] = {string[i], '\0'}; /* create a string */
        push(str); /* and push that */
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d",length);
}
```

Comment: if i follow your correction still I receive error like     "27 8 E:\FALL SEM 20-21\CS\C codes\Untitled3.c [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'push' makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: @Baba_yaga [This works for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fRR84NqdZvByfvbR). Make sure you are compiling your intended source file.